# Taking the first three words of one column in a dataframe and copy them into a new column

Tags: pandas

This seems really simple, but I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to solve. I have a column (col A) containing strings and I want to take the first three words of that string and copy them into a new column (col B).

I have this:

```
col A
Mr Spaghetti Bolognese Piazza Palace
Ms Tagliatelle Carbonara The Real Home of Pasta
Miss Linguine Amatraciana Time to Eat
```

I want to take the name from the first column (i.e. the first three words in the string) and copy them to a new col, like this:

```
col A                                             col B
Mr Spaghetti Bolognese Piazza Palace              Mr Spaghetti Bolognese
Ms Tagliatelle Carbonara The Real Home of Pasta   Ms Tagliatelle Carbonara
Miss Linguine Amatraciana Time to Eat             Miss Linguine Amatraciana
```

I started off with d['col A'].split(' '), which seemed like the right place to start, but I just can't can't access the first three words! Any help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this using str function only like

```py
df["col B"] = df["col A"].str.split().str[:3].str.join(sep=" ")
df
```

Comment: This is it! It really feels like the most Pandasesque solution. It was the str[:3] bit that I didn't know and just couldn't find out about. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
df['col B'] = df['col A'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[:3]))
```

Comment: You need to change 'string' to 'x' and this will work :)

Comment: apologies, I copied straight from a single example and forgot to edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a one-liner:

```
df['frist_three_words'] = df['col A'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: "{} {} {}".format(*x[:3]))
```

First I split the strings and later I use apply with a lambda function. You can easy change the format style of the text.